# How to end a thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm learning how to use asynchronous code in Python.  I want to launch a subprocess and wait for it to finish.  While it's running, I want to monitor the average CPU usage in a thread and print it at the end.  This code is working, but it feels wrong to keep checking `Popen.poll()` repeatedly.  Is there a better way to do this?  I wanted to use `Popen.wait()` but I don't know how to signal another function to break out of a loop.

In this example I'm using `yes` as a test process, and after a few seconds I kill it in a Terminal.

```
def monitor(proc):
    cpu_percents = []
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        cpu_percents.append(psutil.cpu_percent())
        if proc.poll():
            return sum(cpu_percents) / len(cpu_percents)

def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        proc = subprocess.Popen('yes', stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
        thread = executor.submit(monitor, proc)
        cpu_avg = thread.result()

    print('Average CPU usage was {:.1f}%'.format(cpu_avg))
```

Comment: Typically, one uses threads as an _alternative_ to asynchronous code (in the sense of code based on asynchronous/non-blocking syscall interfaces). This looks like it's just threading, not what would conventionally be called async.

Comment: Anyhow, signaling another _thread_ is one thing, but you have another _process_ you want to signal (and you could signal it from either thread, potentially including the main one).

Comment: Popen returns immediately while yes is still running. Isn’t that async?

Comment: Yes, but it's not what people mean when they conventionally talk about asynchronous programming. Running two processes in a manner that isn't in lockstep isn't something you need an async framework or async syscalls to do. What makes tools like Twisted Python and successors special/interesting is support for writing code that multiplexes between handling multiple connections (&c), each with their own state and position in the application's flow of control, while actually only having one thread of control at the OS level.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well the subprocess will finish on its own here. I am trying to figure out how to signal the monitor function to return using Popen.wait() inside main

Comment: If you look at how `psutil` works under-the-hood, it's collecting totals that do nothing but increment over time, and dividing them by the amount of time that elapsed. Given that, you can just collect those totals _twice_, once before you start the process, and once after `wait()`ing for it; and there you are; no need for anything that's asynchronous at all (and certainly no need to do your own averaging of something that is already by nature an average-over-time already).

Comment: Great suggestion! But this is just the beginning. Eventually I want to display real-time CPU, GPU, and disk activity while the process is running.